# CakePhp Error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

I am currently learning how to use CakePhp.

I have created a function in my custom controller as follows:

```
class FormatsController extends AppController
{
    // ....

    function admin_add()
    {

        // if the form data is not empty
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            // initialise the format model
            $this->Format->create();
            // create the slug
            $this->data['Format']['slug'] = $this->slug($this->data['Format']['name']);
            // try saving the format
            if ($this->Format->save($this->data)) {
                // set a flash message
                $this->Session->setFlash('The Format has been saved', 'flash_good');
                // redirect
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                // set a flash message
                $this->Session->setFlash('The Format could not be saved. Please, try again.', 'flash_bad');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However in my view I am getting this error:

> Error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object

Why is this error caused and how can I fix it?

My apologies, I believe the line it is referencing is *not* in the Controller but in my view itself. It refers to my view which has the following line:

```
<?php echo $form->create('Format');?>
```

Is there something else I need to declare before using this? i.e. `$this->Format->create();`

Comment: Refer to my answer below..you should be using that $this->Form->create('Format');

delete your <?php echo $form->create('Format');?> and replace it with <?php echo $this->Form->create('Format');?> 

$form is the one that causes the error.

Comment: In your current controller, you should check property `$uses` like this  `public $uses = array('User', ..  );` We must call model `User` before using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**you should be using:**

```
  $this->Form->create('Format');
```

**delete the**

```
 <?php echo $form->create('Format');?>
```

**and replace it with**

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Format');?>
```

**$form is the one that causes the error.**

Comment: @Imran check this answer

Comment: I used what you said and it worked but the book I was reading told me the other way was right. Actually that book is from 2008 so many things probably has changed since 2008. Thanks.

Comment: @IWannaKnow Yup, cake had a lot of updates :) You must check their official documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html

Comment: I had the same problem following the book "CakePHP Application Development". But also had problems with file anf folder naming. It seems cakePHP changes quite often.

Comment: @theme that's true, that's why sometime I used to trial and error method and sometimes reading other resources aside from the manual and other cake books.

Comment: @zynder it's not a big issue as soon as you can google for the problem and find a quick solution for it, as happen for me with this issue. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Need to define the global name of the model. So, to access it anywhere in application.

For example: my model is User

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';

    function myfunction ($id) {
                  .....
        }
}
To use in controller
Controller: 

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    function test()
    {
      $this->User->myfunction();
        ......
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Could it be that I have defined it in plural `var $name = 'Formats';`? All other functions work despite this such as `$formats = $this->Format->find('all', array('conditions' => array('status' => 1)));`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably being caused because for some reason $this->Format isn't being created. If you look in your code snippet you see it calling the create() function. Add this as a debug statement in your controller function before you call create() to see if it is even set.

```
debug( isset( $this->Format ) );
```

If it is set should output true. If you try this let me know what it says I might have some other suggestions to go from there.

Comment: The Format controller does exist, other functions are being called and are successfully loaded (i.e. view and index). I thought using plural names could have been the issue (its name FormatsController), but if other functions can be loaded this can't be the problem?

Comment: It is not FormatsController.php that you need to verify it is the Model Format.php which according to your code is stored in $this->Format. That is the object that appears to be not defined and you need to test to verify that.

Comment: A method called Format.php has been defined, it contains this line: `var $name = 'Format';`

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the model "Format"? 
This kind of errors arise when the called model has a problem. Either it is not created, or it is not properly created or it is not imported/ initiated properly.

If you declared $uses variable in your controller, make sure you include "Format" in your $uses array along the other models.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one into your action

```
$this->loadModel('Format');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Format
```

is undefined (so it's value is null), a null object has no functions, therefor you can't use

```
$this->Format->create();
```

It's pretty much equal to

```
null->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->Form->create(null,['url' => ['controller' => 'yourController', 'action' => 'yourAction']])
```